# Изменение расположения картинки: PhotoImage object has no attribute 'place'

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу изменить расположение картинки, но что-то ошибку выводит следующую:

`PhotoImage object has no attribute 'place'`

Вот сам код:

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="img.png")
image.place(x=20, y=20)
```

С кнопками такое прокатило, с изображением - нет.)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
label = Label(image=image).place(x=20, y=20)
```